# How to manually make the colorbox loading gif appear?

Tags: ajax, colorbox

I have colorbox configured and the loading gif appears when the window loads but how can I get it to appear when I am calling a page method from whithin the window?

I am calling the method in jScript and it works just fine but the loading gif does not appear so it makes it feel like nothing it happening until my user prompt message appears.

Is there anyway I can call the loading gif in my code?

My jScript is pretty straight forward:

```
// handler for submit button calling page method
    $addHandler($get('SendEmailPageMethod'), 'click', EmailPageMethod);
});

function EmailPageMethod() {
    var name = $get('name').value;
    var email = $get('email').value;
    var message = $get('message').value;

    PageMethods.SendEmail(name, email, message, SuccessCallback, ErrorCallback);
}

function SuccessCallback(resultString) {
    $('#innerForm').addClass('hidden');
    $('div.successMsg').removeClass('hidden');
    //alert(String(resultString));
}

function ErrorCallback(resultString) {
    alert(String(resultString));
    parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
}
```

This jScript is on the parent page that opens the colorbox window:

```
                // handles colorbox for contact form
                $('#contact-form').colorbox({ maxWidth: '75%',
                    close: '',
                    // removes selected class from contact menu item on close
                    onClosed: function () {
                        $('#contact-form').removeClass('selected');
                    }
                });
```

This is what the jScript console says when I open the colorbox form and submit it.

[image]

Comment: why don't you add it as a background image for the element where you are loding colorbox into?

Answer (score 2):

Just query your document for the relevant elements and change their display type:

```
$('#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
```